# Getting a segmentation fault error on an Open Addressing Hash Map?

Tags: c

I'm getting a segmentation fault error somewhere in my insert function. It says that its due to one of the 'strcmp' comparisons but i cant find the issue after looking at all of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 8

typedef struct node
{
    unsigned int val;
    char *key;
    bool del;
} Node;

typedef Node * NodePtr;

typedef struct hashMap
{
    NodePtr array;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
} HashMap;

typedef HashMap * HMPtr;

//|-------------------------

HMPtr create();
void insert(HMPtr map, char *str);
//y
void resize_insert(HMPtr map, char *str);
//y
void print(HMPtr map);
void destroy(HMPtr *mapPtr);
void resize(HMPtr map);
//y
unsigned int hash(char *str);
//y
unsigned int pop(HMPtr map, char *key);
//y

//|-------------------------

int main(void)
{
    HMPtr map = create();
    insert(map, "Keathan");
    insert(map, "Trey");
    insert(map, "Noah");
    insert(map, "Kleiner");
    insert(map, "data");
    insert(map, "Matthew");
    print(map);

    destroy(&map);
    return 0;
}

unsigned int pop(HMPtr map, char *str)
{
    unsigned int val = hash(str);
    size_t h = (size_t)val;
    size_t index = h % map->capacity;

    for(size_t i = 0; map->array[index].key && strcmp(str, map->array[index].key);index = (h + ((++i) + i*i)/2)%map->capacity);

    if (map->array[index].key)
    {
        map->array[index].del = true;
        return map->array[index].val;
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned int hash(char *str)
{
    unsigned int out = 0;
    unsigned int base = 31;
    unsigned int factor = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != 0; ++i)
    {
        out += (unsigned int)str[i] * factor;
        factor *= base;
    }

    return out;
}

void resize(HMPtr map)
{
    NodePtr old = map->array;
    size_t old_capacity = map->capacity;
    map->capacity = old_capacity * 2;
    map->array = calloc(map->capacity, sizeof(Node));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < old_capacity; ++i)
    {
        if(old[i].key)
        {
            if(old[i].del)
                free(old[i].key);
            else
                resize_insert(map, old[i].key);
        }
    }

    free(old);
}

void resize_insert(HMPtr map, char *str)
{
    unsigned int val = hash(str);
    size_t h = (size_t)val;
    size_t index = h % map->capacity;

    for (size_t i = 0; map->array[index].key; index = (h + ((++i) + i*i)/2)%map->capacity);

    map->array[index].key = str;
    map->array[index].val = val;
    ++(map->size);
}

void insert(HMPtr map, char *str)
{
    unsigned int val = hash(str);
    size_t h = (size_t)val;
    size_t index = h % map->capacity;
    size_t i;
    NodePtr deleted = NULL;

    for(i = 0; map->array[index].key && strcmp(str, map->array[index].key);index = (h + ((++i) + i*i)/2)%map->capacity)
        if(!deleted && map->array[index].del)
        {
            deleted = map->array + index;
            for(index = (h + ((++i) + i*i)/2)%map->capacity; map->array[index].key && strcmp(str, map->array[index].key); index = (h + ((++i) + i*i)/2)%map->capacity);
            break;
        }

    if (map->array[index].key == NULL)
    {
        if(deleted)
        {
            free(deleted->key);
            deleted->del = false;
            index = deleted - map->array;
        }
        else if (++(map->size) >= 0.7*map->capacity)
        {
            resize(map);
            index = h % map->capacity;
            for (i = 0; map->array[index].key; index = (h + ((++i) + i*i)/2)%map->capacity);            
        }
        map->array[index].key = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(map->array[index].key, str);
    }
    else 
        map->array[index].val = val;
}

HMPtr create()
{
    HMPtr newList = malloc(sizeof(HashMap));
    newList->size = 0;
    newList->capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    newList->array = calloc(newList->capacity, sizeof(NodePtr));
    return newList;
}

void destroy(HMPtr *mapPtr)
{
    free((*mapPtr)->array);
    free(*mapPtr);
    *mapPtr = NULL;
}

void print(HMPtr map)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < map->capacity; ++i)
        printf("%s;%u\n", map->array[i].key, map->array[i].val);
}
```

This is the Error i recieved after running on gdb

'''
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:30
30      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or
 directory. 
'''

If anyone could spot the issue then that would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: First of all make sure that you build your program with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building with `gcc`). Then when you catch the crash in the debugger, walk `up` the call-stack until you reach your code. Where in your code does it happen?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude looks like it is happening at the first 'strcmp', 7 lines into the insert function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(nodePtr)` is size of `pointer` you need `sizeof(struct Node)`

```
HMPtr create()
{
    HMPtr newList = malloc(sizeof(HashMap));
    newList->size = 0;
    newList->capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    newList->array = calloc(newList->capacity, sizeof(*newList->array));

    return newList;
}
```

Comment: @NoahDavis This is one very common problem with using type-aliases of pointers. It's generally recommended *against* using such type-aliases just to avoid such problems.